# How might a VSCode extension expose a remote repo to the local filesystem?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote, sshfs

I have an excellent tool I use for managing git (https://fork.dev/)

Unfortunately it only works on the local filesystem.

I wonder if there might be a way to create a VSCode extension that can 'mount' the filesystem or a repo on the local machine so tools such as Fork could access it as if locally. Needs to work with more than just git commands (`mmap` for example is used internally within Fork)

Is this even possible?

Comment: This tool can use Github directly - go to File-->Accounts, add Github account and you can list and clone repositories

Comment: why must a VSC extension mount stuff in the OS, All VSC stuff runs in a JavaScript Sandbox

Comment: ... yes? you shouldn't even need to create a VS Code extension to do this. network filesystems, sshfs, etc. but... why not just use VS Code SSH extension and install your tool on the remote machine? do you need to access both local and remote files in the VS Code workspace at the same time?